# To access tinymce iframe elements through jquery

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I an using Tinymce Editor. In need to access tinymce iframe with jquery
I had tried...

```
var iframe = $('#comment_ifr')[0];//document.getElementById('comment_ifr');// or $('#comment_ifr')[0]; the other is just faster.
alert(iframe);
var doc = iframe.document || iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow && iframe.contentWindow.document || null;
   //if( !doc ) return;
   //and now jquery

$( "img", doc ).click(function() {
    alert('image clicked');
   });

----------
```

In my above code once an image inserted in tinymce iframe. Once i click that image i need to trigger an event. Help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get easier to the iframes document by using:

```
var doc = tinymce.get('comment').getDoc();
```

**EDIT:**  To achieve what you want you can catch the click event inside tinymce and do what you wish with it.
You need to insert this code into an own tinymce plugin or use the tinymce init paramater:

```
ed.onClick.add(function(ed, evt){

    // Firefox
    if (evt.explicitOriginalTarget){ // this is the img-element
      if (evt.explicitOriginalTarget.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'img'){
        console.log(evt.explicitOriginalTarget);
        alert('image clicked');
      }
    }
    // IE
    else if (evt.target) { // this is the img-element
      if (evt.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'img'){
        console.log(evt.target);
        alert('image clicked');
      }
    }
}); // end click event
```

Comment: My target is to trigger an onclick event from inserted image in tinymce with jquery. since i m using tinymce jquery version i cant use ur code myfriend

Comment: you can, jquery build of tinymce is compatible with good old javascript (and the above uses valid tinymce functions)

Comment: I used the jquery tinymce build some time ago and found out that is slows down processing of input data (characters) by the factor of 4-6 compared to the normal javascript build. Now i load the regular jquery lib and the normal tinymce lib for performance reasons.

Comment: Its possible to trigger an event while i click an inserted image inside tinymce in jquery? Explain me with sample code

Comment: yes it is using tinymces dispatching functions - see my edited post

Comment: Thank u friend, Its works for me. If u know how to pass all attributes of clicked image through ur function. Pl explain me

Comment: you can get all attributes of your images (you acces the image element using evt.explicitOriginalTarget (FF) or evt.target(IE) ); just printi t out using firebug and console.log(evt.target);

Comment: please edit and show in ur answer. since i am not familiar with dispatch functions

Comment: i strongly suggest using firebug for web debugging; console.log(evt.target); will let show you the img-element in the firebug console (see my edited post)

Comment: This codes wont works in ie7. i dont know where is problem. onclicking an image i am opening popup window to edit image. this codes wont works in ie7

Comment: @thariama. once i click image inside tinymce, a small icon link to display on top of image. once i click that image i need to trigger edit func of image(your answer). whether it is possible

Comment: you should have a look at the contextmenu plugin, using this plugin you may do a right-click on an image and trigger exactly that action

Comment: My brother, I dont like to use plugins of tinymce. Since i am developing Advanced tinymce browser as same as wordpress. I like to do it with jquery script. so only i had preffered jquery tinymce. give me an idea how to do edit option as same as wordpress.

Comment: Thariama give me some tutorial to learn how to write plugins in tinymce. Help me brother since i need to bring edit option as same as wordpress

Comment: here is a tutoruial on how to create a plugin: http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Create_plugin/3.x

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("#comment_ifr").contents().filter("img").click(function() {
    alert('clicked');
});
```

Comment: var doc = tinymce.get('comment').getDoc();
Since i use jquery version i cant use this..

Comment: Okay, just try `alert($("#comment_ifr").contents());`. Do you get anything?

Comment: $("#comment_ifr").contents().find("img").click(function() {
    alert('clicked');
});
By using this code i cant access image inside that iframe. If iframe is a link it cant be easy to access its element but tinymce iframe is built as result of javascript. i think so only i cant access.

Comment: $("#check").click(function() {
 alert($("#comment_ifr").contents());

});
 I tried ur code with check button. I get [object][Object] as alert. My target is to trigger an onclick event from inserted image in tinymce

Comment: @Mohan - I've edited (`filter` instead of `find`). Maybe give that a go.

Comment: Its not working for me :-( .I cant access tinymce iframe inside content. i dont know why.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using version 4, you can access elements in the iframe like this:

1.) If you have direct access to the editor object:

```
tinymce.init({
  setup : function(editor) {
    editor.dom.$('#thingId');
  }
});
```

2.) If you don't have direct access to the editor object:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.dom.$('#thingId');
```

Answer (score 0):

For tinyMCE before version 4 (ie tinymce 3.5.12 and less) you have to set

```
var iframe = $('#editable_container_ifr');
var editorContent = $('#tinymce[id="tinymce"]', iframe.contents()).html();
console.log(editorContent);
```

into the script for jquery

`editable_container` is the id of your textearea

Because with tinyMCE 4 the emoticons don't work I reverted to 3.3.12 and everything works

Answer (score -1):

**This is my final code to get source of an image inside tinymce editor**

```
ed.onClick.add(function(ed, evt){

    // Firefox
    if (evt.explicitOriginalTarget){ // this is the img-element
      if (evt.explicitOriginalTarget.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'img'){
        alert(evt.explicitOriginalTarget.src);
      }
    }
    // IE
    else if (evt.target) { // this is the img-element
      if (evt.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'img'){
        alert(evt.target.src);
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: -1 for copying my answer and refusing to accept mine (it is nasty to not give credit to the author)

Comment: thx, for correcting this issue - it is kind of frustrating to spent time to solve other peoples issues and then not to earn the reputation for this (removed the -1)