# Wordpress: add events inside TinyMCE iframe

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, tinymce, wordpress-theming

I've added some div wrapper styles to Wordpress, but when I use them in the page, it is impossible to add content below them in the page.  CSS:after works inside the divs to create a selectable area, but it doesn't work to create a selectable area after the div.

In my functions.php I have:

```
  function my_mce_before_init( $settings ) {
    $style_formats = array(
        array(
            'title' => 'Box Two Columns',
            'block' => 'div',
            'classes' => 'twocolbox',
            'wrapper' => true
        ),
        array(
            'title' => 'Image with Caption',
            'block' => 'div',
            'classes' => 'img_caption',
            'wrapper' => true
        ),
        array(
            'title' => 'Gallery Horizontal',
            'block' => 'div',
            'classes' => 'scroller horizontal',
            'wrapper' => true
        )
    );

    $settings['style_formats'] = json_encode( $style_formats );
    return $settings;

}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'my_mce_before_init');
add_editor_style();
```

Is there a way to use execCommand here to add some html after the div styles I defined?  To add something like an empty paragraph tag afterwards with a clear float?

I tried:

```
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceInsertContent',false,'Hello world!!');"
```

MCE editor breaks then.

...
Tried this but it's too buggy:
In editor-styles.css:

```
#tinyMCE:after {
 content: "    ";
 clear:both;
 width: 4em; height:4em;
}
```

Note that you may need to clear cache AND shift-reload button to see any changes to editor-styles.css in Wordpress.

...

Still working on this.  Found a thread:
[To access tinymce iframe elements through jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312173/to-access-tinymce-iframe-elements-through-jquery)

I tried adding the code in this thread to my_mce_before_init, but it just broke.

....
Also tried loading a jQuery script, but the target paths wouldn't work on the TinyMCE iframe.  None of these selectors work:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $("#tinyMCE").find("div").after('<p style="width:100%; clear:both; height:1em;">&nbsp; 6789</p>');
     $("div").css("color","red");

    $("#content_ifr").contents().find("div").after('<p style="width:100%; clear:both; height:1em;">&nbsp; 6789</p>');
    $("#content_ifr").contents().find("#tinymce p").css("color","red");

    $("#wp-content-editor-container").find("textarea").css("color","red");
    $("iframe").contents().find("p").css("color","red");

    $('#content_ifr').load(function(){
        $('#content_ifr').contents().find('p').css("color","red");
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add html pseudo elements using the tinymce configuration option content_css.
There you can define after elements. Give it a try!

**Update:**

When initializing tinymce set the setup paramter to the following (inside `tinyMCE.init({...}`)

```
...
theme: "advanced",   // example param
setup : function(ed) {
    ed.onInit.add(function(ed, evt) {
        $("#content_ifr").contents().find("p").css("color","red");

        // other approach  
        //$(ed.getBody()).find('p').css("color","red");
    });
},
cleanup: true,      // example param
...
```

Comment: Hi Thariama, css:after was very buggy about creating a selectable area in MCE.   Possibly setContent would work, if I knew how to put it in functions.php or how to get my jquery to target the MCE iframe.

Comment: you may target the editor iframe using $("#" + ed.id + "_ifr") when ed is the tinymce editor object

Comment: I tried loading a Jquery script and using: $('#content_ifr').contents().find('p').css("color","red");
Maybe if I change to document load event?  You're saying the target wasn't the problem, so it must be the load order?

Comment: jQuery(document).ready(function($) won't work because at that point of time there is still no editor instance ready (and no iframe created). to make it work you should use an onInitHandler plus the tinymce configuration parameter setup (place your code inside that handler!)

Comment: This is the part I don't understand - how and where to put onInitHandler.

Comment: Still lost. You said to place this inside TinyMCE init, but where's that?  :) I tried again to edit the php in my functions.php file, to no avail.  Since you used jQuery, did you replace the editor with Jquery version?  Like here? http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/jquery_version.php  If so, should I deregister the default editor  in functions.php or something?

Comment: no, i do not use the tinymce jQuery build (and i strongly suggest not to use this source of trouble!), but i have regular jQuery loaded on my main document. TinyMCE init is the function that initializes your editor, but there might be an addControl execute-statement somewhere else.